# Bootstrap modal dialog tabindex="-1" not accessable form elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap modal dialog and this modal dialog have a tabindex="-1" attribute and in this modal form elements working properly..
I'm call a fixed other div with have form elements. But this form elements cannot accessable. The cursor looks normal when the form elements hover over them. But when I click it doesn't focus.

If I remove tab index = "-1", it's okay. But I need the tabindex = "-1" attribute.

Following html bootstrap modal dialog..

```
    <div class="modal fade" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" data-bind="modal:$parent.Edit">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Ekle/Düzenle</h4>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="inner-padding">
                        @Html.Partial("FieldItem")
                        <!--Some form elements for modal dialog this form elements working properly-->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="float:none;" data-dismiss="modal">Kapat</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And following html called div with form elements. Not in bootstrap modal dialog and not accessable

```
<div id="value-popup" role="dialog" onclick="event.stopPropagation()"  style="width:300px;padding:15px;z-index:99999;position:fixed;left:0px;top:0px;background-color:white; border-radius:5px;border:1px solid #808080" data-bind="visible:Show, style:{left:PanelPos().x + 'px',top:PanelPos().y + 'px'}">

    <div class="form-group" style="padding:15px;">
        <label class="control-label">Ara</label>
        <input  type="text" placeholder="Ara" data-bind="textInput:Keyword,hasFocus:SearchFocus" class="form-control value-helper-search"  onclick="event.stopPropagation()" />
    </div>
    <select size="20" class="form-control" data-bind="foreach:Result,value:SelectedItem" onclick="event.stopPropagation()" >
        <optgroup label="x" data-bind="attr:{label:Name},foreach:FilteredItems">
            <option data-bind="value:$data, text: Name"></option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, tab index can't be same ,As TabIndex specifies order in which focus on that element should work,It must be unique index.

E.g. we have 2 buttons in html, firs is "OK" with tab index=1" and other  is "cancel" with tab index "2"

when user hits "tab" key, it will first focus on "OK" button", next if we again hit Tab key, Now it will  focus on "Cancel" button.

So TableIndex must be unique,to work as it is made for.

Comment: I have no problem with tab hits. The fixed div bootstrap I invoke appears above the modal dialogue. But if the modal dialog has tabindex = "- 1", I cannot focus even though I click on the form elements in the fixed div.

Comment: this happens because your z-index. your z index of div is more than bootstrap modal, this is overlappting bootstrap model. try to remove z index in div